# moving a file crashes Finder with kernel Code Signing error

Tags: macos, finder

When I move a file, either into another folder or the Trash, Finder crashes and relaunches, and the file doesn't get moved. This also happens when I try to empty the trash. Console shows a couple of error messages after this. First, it says a crash report was saved, and there's a message like this:

3/12/14 4:13:16.000 PM kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: process 5905[Finder]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x1030eb000 from offset 0x1a9000 in file "ﾭ�ﾭ�/Users/myusername/Documents/Folder1" (cs_mtime:0.0 == mtime:0.0) (signed:0 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

EDIT:

There are some other messages that get posted, too:

```
3/13/14 9:33:10.000 AM kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x10da2a000): p=1334[Finder] final status 0x1000a00, denying page sending SIGKILL
3/13/14 9:33:10.000 AM kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: process 1334[Finder]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x10da2a000 from offset 0x1a9000 in file "ﾭ�ﾭ�/Users/myusername/Documents/Folder1" (cs_mtime:0.0 == mtime:0.0) (signed:0 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)
3/13/14 9:33:11.000 AM kernel[0]: CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x10e9f6000): p=1379[ReportCrash] final status 0x0, allowing (remove VALID) page
3/13/14 9:33:11.268 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[249]: (com.apple.Finder[1334]) Exited: Killed: 9
3/13/14 9:33:11.862 AM ReportCrash[1379]: Saved crash report for Finder[1334] version 10.9.2 (10.9.2) to /Users/myusername/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Finder_2014-03-13-093311_Ny-Computer-iMac.crash
3/13/14 9:33:11.871 AM xpcproxy[1382]: assertion failed: 13C64: xpcproxy + 3438 [D559FC96-E6B1-363A-B850-C7AC9734F210]: 0x2
```

And here's the crash report (it's too big to fit in the box, which is why I didn't want to post it originally): http://pastebin.com/TTT2v6Rb

Comment: The crash report itself would be more instructive than those lines, it seems to me.

Comment: This is quite strange. Do all / any file moves do this? Can you rename your HD to see if that's related? If you reboot, does the issue get better/worse or is it stable across boots? If you search for i/o errors in console.app - are there any?

Comment: Yes--thanks for asking. I tried rebooting, and it seems consistent. Also, renaming the hard drive doesn't change things.

Comment: The solution was just to reinstall OS X: everything was fine after that. Never could figure out exactly how this happened or what was going on. Weird.